# images keep changing repeatedly when using a recycled view in a custom adapter - android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, custom-adapter

I have the following code for my custom adapter, in which each row consists from a name, and a picture, which is taken from the firebase storage:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageException;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.List;

public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    List<RowItem> rowItems;


    CustomAdapter(Context context, List<RowItem> rowItems) {
        this.context = context;
        this.rowItems = rowItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return rowItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    /* private view holder class */
    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView profile_pic;
        TextView member_name;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        final RowItem row_pos = rowItems.get(position);

        final StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child(row_pos.getFirebaseUserUid()+".jpg");




        //if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);


        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.member_name = convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.member_name);
        holder.profile_pic = convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);





        //convertView.setTag(holder);


        /*} else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }*/

        holder.member_name.setText(row_pos.getName());



        storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new 
OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {





 Glide.with(context).load(uri).apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform()).into(holder.profile_pic);
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            int errorCode = ((StorageException) exception).getErrorCode();
            if (errorCode == StorageException.ERROR_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND) {
                Picasso.get()
                        .load(R.drawable.user)
                        .resize(70,70)
                        .into(holder.profile_pic);
            }
        }
    });


    return convertView;
    }

}
```

Now, if I run it like this, it will load every new row, and thus the scrolling won't be as smooth as I would like it to be.
To overcome this, Many posts suggested to add the following (Basically what is marked as comments in the code above):

```
if (convertView == null){
    /.../
    convertView.setTag(holder);
}

} else {
      holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}
```

But when I do that, in the profilePic view of the list item, it displays quite fast many images one after the other.

Can anyone please help in detecting the problem and suggesting any solutions?

Here is a video of the bug: https://vimeo.com/271555362

Comment: Use RecyclerView instead of Listview

Comment: Is there any other option? I don't want to rewrite a lot of my code

Comment: Why not get the Urls when you create the list of `RowItem` instead of doing async calls in the middle of your Adapter? An Adapter is supposed to display data not retrieve them. It'll simplify the code and get rid off a part of the latency.
And this is not the issue here, but why are you using both Glide and Picasso?! Choose one.

Comment: have you checked if the problem resides into recycling process?

Comment: @Eselfar I can't get the url and then call the adapter, since then the adapter is being called without the url (because it takes time to get the url, and in that time the adapter is being called)

Comment: @firegloves Sorry, I don't really understand what you mean by that

Comment: The problem in requesting the URLs in the Adapter is that you need to manually stop the request to Firebase when the view (row) is reused.
It depends on how many items you have and how long it takes to retrieve the urls, but you could display an empty list with a progressbar while retrieving the urls and then display the list when you have all the elements to do so.

Comment: I mean: maybe when a recycled item view come back into visible screen it has it's old image, then it try to load te new one obtaining the effect you speak about

Comment: adding info to Eselfar comment: you could set a default local image that is loaded when your recycled view come into visible screen, the you could start loading real image

Comment: @Eselfar the problem is, that right now it loads quite slow, and when the user scrolls it loads the new picture also really slow, thus scrolling is quite annoying. Even if added the progressbar it will still be quite uncomfortable to scroll.

Comment: @firegloves I don't understand what you mean:
 - if you mean doing so in the code that does recycle the view, then I tried it and it keeps doing it
 - if you mean to add this in the code that I gave above then please refer to the comment I wrote before to Eselfar

Comment: Ok, can you post a short video to see precisely the effect you speak about?

Comment: Before implementing anything, you need to understand how a ListView works (an particularly, its adapter). The Adapter has a certain number of views and reuses them to display the data when you scrolls. For instance, if you have 100 items in your list but you can see only 10 of them at the same time, the listview will try to manage only 10 views. If you don't write your adapter correctly and creates a new view every time `getView` is called, do operations on non used views or when the content has changed, you'll end with leaks, and a slow UI.

Comment: This is what @firegloves means when he talks about the 'recycling process'. So I'd advise you to read some documentation on the best practices to implement a ListView. And as mentioned above it''s better to use a RecyclerView anyway

Comment: @firegloves added a video to the post

Comment: You are not scrolling? Or that is the moment when the item that blink is just entered in the view?

Comment: It actually happens twice - first, when the activity is loaded, and second, when I scroll down. It doesn't happen in all of the views tho, only in two of them

Comment: let me know if my solution works

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that one indicated by Eselfar.
When you request the uri to firebase it should be done on an async thread. That means that in the meanwhile the url of iteration n is retrieved the adapter continues iterating on your list.

This 2 flows are executed simultaneously, so holder variable is constantly reassigned, probably until the iteration reach its last visible item (view).

That results into this scenario:

```
for each view {
   request image url       (for example 2 seconds)
   assign holder variable  (for example 0.0002 seconds)
}
```

in the meanwhile that the first image url is retrieven (2 seconds) the adapter have ended the iteration.
So holder variable now have the same value, that is the last value of the entire iteration.
After 2 seconds for the first image url (and so on for the remaining image url) it enters into `OnSuccessListener.onSuccess` method, it set with Glide the image on the `holder.profile_pic` variable. But that variable, as said previously, now belongs to the last iteration done.

So your problem is that you are mixing sync and async approach.

A possibile solution is to retrieve first all image urls, then remove that async task (`storageReference.getDownloadUrl()`) and do all the stuff in the same UIThread.

I think the simplest solution (but probably not the best) is to create a custom OnSuccessListener and a custom OnFailureListener like this:

```
public class MySuccessListener extends OnSuccessListener {


          Holder holder;

            public MySuccessListener(Holder holder) {
            this.holder = holder;
            super();
          }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                Glide.with(context).load(uri).apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform()).into(holder.profile_pic);
          }
}

public class MyFailureListener extends OnFailureListener {


          Holder holder;

            public MyFailureListener(Holder holder) {
            this.holder = holder;
            super();
          }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception)
                int errorCode = ((StorageException) exception).getErrorCode();
                 if (errorCode == StorageException.ERROR_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND) {
                    Picasso.get()
                        .load(R.drawable.user)
                        .resize(70,70)
                        .into(holder.profile_pic);
                 }
          }
}
```

Note that you pass current holder into your listeners constructors, so when async task ends you can target correct holder.
Then you can update your code like so:

```
storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new MyFailureListener<Uri>(holder))
                            .addOnFailureListener(new MyFailureListener(holder));
```

Now I can’t test it into and IDE my code could be imprecise, but basically you should understand suggested way.

Note that you are using Picasso and Glide. This two libs do the same stuff, I suggest you to use one of them and remove the unnecessary dependency.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Your first solution - I didn't find any way to stop that `storageReference.getDownloadUrl()` async task, nothing I tried seemed to work...

As for the other solution, I don't really see a way of doing it... maybe you have any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what  storageReference.getDownloadUrl() contains? A link to an image like http://www.xxx.yyy/image.jpg?

Comment: Yes, exactly what you said